# Как включить русские буквы в mercurial?

Tags: кодировка, mercurial

В системе управления версиями Mercurial русские буквы отображаются неправильно. Работаю в командной строке. При комите пишу описание на русском. Потом смотрю вывод `hg log` и вижу в summary кракозябры. Пробовал `hg log --encoding=utf-8`, ничего не меняется. Как победить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это происходит под windows, то, возможно, у вас не совпадает кодировка консоли (866) и та в которой вы делаете комментарий при коммите (1251 скорее всего).  Переключить консоль на 1251 можно командой `> chcp 1251`. Или же выводить комменты в кодировке 866: `> hg log --encoding=866`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. С этим разобрался, теперь другое вылезло. Теперь проблема на самом сайте bitbucket при просмотре Files Changed, когда показаны изменения в файле с + в начале и зеленым цветом. В этом режиме опять не та кодировка. Хотя просто при просмотре файла кодировка нормальная.